# Cakephp -how to use and where to put debug($var) in $this?

Tags: ajax, debugging, cakephp, this, json

I want to know the value of the associative array $this in cakephp, base on my research I could use debug($this);
however I don't know where to put it, model, view or controller, and I don't know where to see the result of debug($this);.

I'm trying to get the value of $this so that I can use them in making a rest api using json_encode.

To elaborate the process

Content or what is inside of $this(part which I want to see)

json_encode

ajax

any help suggestions or opinions is highly appreciated

Comment: debug() is a global function.  You can put it in models, views, or controllers, nearly anywhere really, and it will work.  You'll see the output at the top of your page if you use it in a controller or a model, or you'll see it wherever you added it in your view.  You do not want to use debug() for anything other than debugging.  Debug automatically displays whatever you passed to debug, yes, but it also adds markup and javascript, since the debug output is styled and such.

Comment: @Kai can I do debug($this); or should I change the parameter? because I tried debug($this) and I didn't see any result. In showing the output of the associative array $this, is debug($var) the proper function or var_dump or print_r? by the way tnx for the feedback

Comment: Yes, you can do debug($this).  Take a look a the page's source to see if the debug output was added to the page in a place where it wouldn't actually be visibly displayed.  Of course though, I have no idea what $this is, so for all I know it may be undefined wherever you are trying to use debug($this);  You should also get something if you use var_dump, though it probably won't be as detailed as debug();

Comment: @kai tnx for your feedbacks.i think i know how to get what i want